# Unable to Open Com Port

Tags: serial-port

Hi AskUbuntu community.

I want ask a question about the opening of serial ports in Ubuntu. I use Ubuntu 20.04 in my MSI computer.

I want to access a hardware device (A GPS unit) via USB cable. I installed the ROS2 driver of the device and tried the below code example:
`ros2 launch sbg_driver sbg_device_launch.py`

After that I got the error message: **sbgInterfaceSerialCreate: Unable to open the com port: /dev/sbg**

To fix the error, I added myuser to **dialout and tty groups** but the error did not be fixed.

Can you help me?

*** The screenshot about the error is below: [Serial Port Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGc0t.png)

Comment: After plugging in the USB device what does the output of lsusb give you?

Comment: Hi @Simon Banks, the output is: ' Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC ' So, the computer can see the USB device.

Comment: Is there a device /dev/sbg to begin with?

Comment: @Sebastian if you talking about the computer environment or the directory **dev**, No, there is not any such file like sbg in dev directory. 

But, the device I want to use as a GPS is a SBG device.

Comment: That's what I thought. That means somewhere in the script you launch it specifies to look for a device /dev/sbg. Usually virtual COM ports like this device seems to use register under something like /dev/ttyACM0 or /dev/ttyUSB0. You can try to check the output of `dmesg` right after plugging it in to get a hint. Then you would have to adapt the script to use the port the device uses. If they support Linux, SBG should have some support on their website for that, or is the script you're using your own?

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks for your answer. As you told, the output of the dmesg is say that a device is connected to the ttyUSB0 port.
I viewed the script for the SBG driver. The port name is about deviceName in this script. But I could not find the declaration name of this paramater. (deviceName).
I asked the support center for the SBG device. I am waiting for answer.

Comment: @Sebastian I fixed my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @mfatih can you share the fixe please? thank you